# How to determine which standard is used by wifi ap/network?

Tags: android, wifi

I would like to determine with android `code` the standard used by the `WiFi` connection `:802.11 a,b ,g ...`

I saw a lot of Android applications that give the standard.
If there is a specific class, or tutorial, please make me aware.

Thank you.

Comment: use capabilities of wifiscanlist

Comment: i'm getting information about wfifi :BSSid ,frequency,capabilities..i can know now the channel used by the connexion from the frequency ,but still don't know how to get the norme.